# adding a custom header in http request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, http-get

I need to add a custom header to the $http.get method, I did not understand how to do it.

```
var hello = _helper.server.http($http, url)
    .success(function(response){
        //do something
    });
```

How do I add a custom header ('X-user') and a corresponding value (say: "pqrs") ?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Every $http method takes a config object as argument, and this config object contains headers.

Comment: could you post more code? You could be making a mistake in the http function in _helper.server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming _helper.server.http is a different function, I think you are making a mistake while passing the header

You have to send the header as a object

```
var customHeader = {'X-user': 'pqrs'}
```

to

```
var hello = _helper.server.http($http, url, customHeader)
```

and under the function http in _helper.server, you have to add the headers there and then call the http post method,

```
http: function($http, urlParam, param) {
    var request = {
        url: urlParam,
        headers: param
    };

    return $http.post(request);
}
```

It would help if you post more code, this could be the mistake that you are making

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the config :

```
var config = {headers:  {
        "X-user" : "pqrs"
    }
};

$http.get(url, config).success(function(response){
   //Do something
});
```

Comment: i tried the above solution, i am still unable to set the header

Comment: @swordfish12, please check the documentation, this is how its done, you must have done a mistake elsewhere